# Backbone router configuration on dynamic page

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-routing

I have a php page that is loaded up via a get request and contains multiple params like: index.php?page=6&name=Virginia.  Once the page is loaded I then initalize backbone and am using it to render views on a portion of the page.  The problem is that the router appears to be taking my entire url and registering it so that in order to trigger a route I have to append the following to my links:  .  This works but it's ugly.  I've tried changing the root parameter to Backbone.history.start but can't seem to get it to work right.  I'm sure most people don't start backbone from a dynamic page with query params but any help is appreciated.  I've tried various solutions from plugins to different regexes but to no avail.

Comment: This is not a typical Backbone router case. Is your pushState true or false?

Comment: I know it's not typical but I've tried setting both pushState to true/false and was unsuccessful in either event.

Answer (score 0):

Without pushState you can't do this at all. I would do something like:

```
var router = Backbone.Router.extend({
  routes: {
    '*url': 'defaultRoute'
  },

  defaultRoute: function(url) {
    // just url argument and parse params out
  }
});
```

That in fact would be the easiest in your case. And for params, you need a class with `get`, `set`, and `delete` methods, that's pretty simple and you can find a ton of examples.

Comment: Thanks for the example but this still won't work as I still need to match the query params in the links otherwise backbone won't intercept the event correctly and the browser navigates away.

Comment: No, actually this will catch ALL url changes. BTW you never showed your code. At least it would help if you showed `routes` declaration.

Comment: Hi again, it doesn't catch all url changes (I'm running a super simplified example right now with just the code snippet you've posted) and it still doesn't work.  After debugging backbone a bit, I believe the problem is this: a) backbone registers changes to the url by calling: $(window).bind('hashchange', this.checkUrl); .  In order for this event to be properly fired, I need to keep the same dynamic parameters in the link that fires the click event, otherwise backbone is never notified of the change.  I suppose this is more of a implementation of the haschange event.